# is there a way to get Spark Tracking URL other than mining log files for the log output?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have an Scala application that creates a Spark Session and I have set up health checks that use the Spark REST API. The Spark Application itself runs on Hadoop Yarn. The REST API URL is currently retrieved by reading the Spark logging generated when the Spark Session is created. This works most of the time but there are some edge cases in my application where it doesn't work so well.
Does anyone know of another way to get this tracking URL?

Comment: I raised an enhancement request: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20458

Answer (score 0):

"You can do this by reading the `yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address` value from YARN's config and the application ID (which is exposed both in an event sent on the listener bus, and an existing SparkContext method."

Copied the paragraph above as is from the developer's response found at: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20458

UPDATE:

I did try the solution and got pretty close. Here's some Scala/Spark code to build that URL:

```
@transient val ssc: StreamingContext = StreamingContext.getActiveOrCreate(rabbitSettings.checkpointPath, CreateStreamingContext)

// Update yarn logs URL in Elasticsearch
YarnLogsTracker.update(
  ssc.sparkContext.uiWebUrl,
  ssc.sparkContext.applicationId,
  "test2")
```

And the `YarnLogsTracker` object goes something like this:

```
object YarnLogsTracker {

  private def recoverURL(u: Option[String]): String = u match {
    case Some(a) => a.split(":").take(2).mkString(":")
    case None => ""
  }

 def update(rawUrl: Option[String], rawAppId: String, tenant: String): Unit = {
   val logUrl = s"${recoverURL(rawUrl)}:8042/node/containerlogs/container${rawAppId.substring(11)}_01_000002/$tenant/stdout/?start=-4096"
...
```

Which produces something like this: `http://10.99.25.146:8042/node/containerlogs/container_1516203096033_91164_01_000002/test2/stdout/?start=-4096`

Comment: I believe the `/proxy/` URL is the best way here.  I have added an expanded answer that incorporates this in the construction of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered a "reasonable" way to obtain this.  Obviously, the best way would be for Spark libraries to expose the `ApplicationReport` that they're already fetching to the launcher application directly, since they go to the trouble of setting delegation tokens, etc.  However, this seems unlikely to happen.

This approach is two-pronged.  First, it attempts to build a `YarnClient` itself, in order to fetch the `ApplicationReport`, which will have the authoritative tracking URL.  However, from my experience, this can fail (ex: if the job was run in `CLUSTER` mode, with a `--proxy-user` in a Kerberized environment, then this will not be able to properly authenticate to YARN).

In my case, I'm calling this helper method from the driver itself, and reporting the result back to my launcher application on the side.  However, in principle, any place where you have the Hadoop `Configuration` available should work (including, possibly, your launcher application).  You can obviously use either "prong" of this implementation (or both) depending on your needs and tolerance for complexity, extra processing, etc.

```
  /**
   * Given a Hadoop {@link org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration} and appId, use the YARN API (via an
   * {@link YarnClient} instance) to get the application report, which includes the trackingUrl.  If this fails,
   * then as a fallback, it attempts to "guess" the URL by looking at various YARN configuration properties,
   * and assumes that the URL will be something like: <pre>[yarnWebUI:port]/proxy/[appId]</pre>.
   *
   * @param hadoopConf the Hadoop {@link org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration}
   * @param appId the YARN application ID
   * @return the app trackingUrl, either retrieved using the {@link YarnClient}, or manually constructed using
   *         the fallback approach
   */
  public static String getYarnApplicationTrackingUrl(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration hadoopConf, String appId) {
    LOG.debug("Attempting to look up YARN url for applicationId {}", appId);
    YarnClient yarnClient = null;
    try {
      // do not attempt to fail over on authentication error (ex: running with proxy-user and Kerberos)
      hadoopConf.set("yarn.client.failover-max-attempts", "0");
      yarnClient = YarnClient.createYarnClient();
      yarnClient.init(hadoopConf);
      yarnClient.start();

      final ApplicationReport report = yarnClient.getApplicationReport(ConverterUtils.toApplicationId(appId));
      return report.getTrackingUrl();
    } catch (YarnException | IOException e) {
      LOG.warn(
          "{} attempting to get report for YARN appId {}; attempting to use manually constructed fallback",
          e.getClass().getSimpleName(),
          appId,
          e
      );

      String baseYarnWebappUrl;
      String protocol;
      if ("HTTPS_ONLY".equals(hadoopConf.get("yarn.http.policy"))) {
        // YARN is configured to use HTTPS only, hence return the https address
        baseYarnWebappUrl = hadoopConf.get("yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.https.address");
        protocol = "https";
      } else {
        baseYarnWebappUrl = hadoopConf.get("yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address");
        protocol = "http";
      }

      return String.format("%s://%s/proxy/%s", protocol, baseYarnWebappUrl, appId);
    } finally {
      if (yarnClient != null) {
        yarnClient.stop();
      }
    }
  }
```